# Git: show inline diff within context of full file

Tags: git, diff

How can I view the full contents of a file, at a given revision, with 'inline' diffs; i.e. new lines prefixed with plus, lines that were removed prefixed with a minus, etc?

Comment: Do none of [these suggestions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338126/how-to-diff-the-same-file-between-two-different-commits-on-the-same-branch) work for you?

Comment: @nerdwaller I can't spot any that would, based on their descriptions

Answer (score 3):

Based on my answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24932000/706561):

```
git show 0a1b2c3 --no-prefix -U1000
```